# Why does "cd -" behave as it does?

Tags: linux, cd

What does `cd -` exactly do ? ( the change directory command, plus a dash )

I noticed that if I run it in my `/home/user` folder repeatedly it outputs either `/home/user` or `/home`, this changes if I run it from a different folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd -
```

pop the last directory you were from the stack of directory. It's like hitting "back" on the browser.

Exemple :

you are in /user/alex

you can test that with :
   pwd 
that give you 
   /user/alex

then if you do

```
%cd project1/subfolder
%pwd 
/user/alex/project1/subfolder
%cd subsubfolder
%pwd
/user/alex/project1/subfolder/subsubfolder
%cd - 
pwd 
/user/alex/project1/subfolder
cd - 
pwd 
/user/alex
```

NB : it's not going back a level upper in the folder hierarchy. it's going to the previous current folder. ( a level upper is `cd ..` ).

Comment: Perfect, i was able to find `pushd` and `popd` due to your explanation to better understand this. Thank you!

Comment: then validate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
cd -
```

allows you to switch back to the "last directory you were in when you changed to the current directory".  Running the command twice allows you to switch back to the current directory (since the current directory would then become the "last directory you were in when you changed to the current directory").

This is very useful if you are in a very long directory which you don't want to type out over and over, and you go to another lengthy named directory.  Instead of retyping it, you can just do a 'cd -', which is similar to how some people use the alt-tab (or command-tab) to switch between applications.  This key combo shortcut lets you essentially toggle between the last two applications.

Answer (score 0):

cd stands for Change Directory

It is used to navigate arond your folders

So if you're in /home/user and have a folder in that directory called 'top-secret', you would access it by typing:

```
cd /top-secret
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood , I know cd changes directories but why does "cd -" change the directory an also outputs to stdout what it does ?